# Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticSearch.Path is deprecated, what should I use instead?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch.net

In [ElasticSearch.Net](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net) v.5 there is a property [`Elasticsearch.Net.RequestData.Path`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Elasticsearch.Net/Transport/Pipeline/RequestData.cs) which has been [deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/6.x/elasticsearch-net-breaking-changes.html) in ElasticSearch.Net v.6. What should I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the history in github, `Path` gets replaced with a more descriptive property, `PathAndQuery`. If you look at the constructor, both [`Path`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/94ac52a1efd0388c7cf94d10c907501f7560a2fc/src/Elasticsearch.Net/Transport/Pipeline/RequestData.cs#L57) and [`PathAndQuery`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/7fc9ca09ec520b59df83edca0c4aeee13cf76751/src/Elasticsearch.Net/Transport/Pipeline/RequestData.cs#L22) are set using the `CreatePathWithQueryStrings(...)` method.

Comment: Thankyou. (I did as you wrote, ahead of posting, but didn't know how far down the rabbit hole I should care to go. I lost stamina at the [commit](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/pull/3016) where `Path` was dropped and `PathAndQuery` came to life, as I found no explicit clue that they were the same. Had I followed the rabbit into the constructor I would probably not have had to ask.)